# Aligning form component using Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm making a form with help of bootstrap4 and it has to be like this :

[image: Form]

Since I have already done my homework reading by reading the content from [Bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/). And tried my level best to make the form like this but after all this, I'm not getting the desired result. I have used the  for achieving the result but no luck.

This is the code which I have tried so far :

**Mypage.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-container">
   <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="number" class="form-control box" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone Number">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-inline">
      <label class="mr-sm-2">Bio</label>
      <div class="circle">i</div>

      <label for="inputBio" class="mr-sm-2"></label>
      <div class="col">
        <textarea class="form-control bio-text" id="inputBio" rows="3" placeholder="Your Bio"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.form-container { max-width: 449px }
.box { margin-left: 82px }

.bio-text { height: 91px; margin-left: 28px }

input[type="number"] {border: 2px solid #b1b1b1; padding: .55rem .75rem} 
textarea {border: 2px solid #b1b1b1; padding: .55rem .75rem}

.circle { width: 22px; height: 22px; border-radius: 50%; color: white;
       line-height: 20px; text-align: center; background: rgb(162, 197, 252); margin-left: 50px}
```

This is the link to my code where I have tried this : [JSFiddle code for the form](https://jsfiddle.net/alok_kumar_verma/3823q52w/1/)

I have also taken the screenshot from my browser which looks like this :

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Please consider me as a learner since I'm new to the web and moreover new to bootstrap4. Thanks

Comment: Like phone, you need to give a col-sm-2 instead of mr-sm-2 for bio LABEL and for the text area div,it should be <div class="col-sm-10">

Comment: @HemaNandagopal Not working out as the box comes below the Bio. You can try it on my jsfiddle link. It is not working out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made some minor changes in layout. Seems the output is as you needed. :)

```css
.form-container { max-width: 449px }
.box { margin-left: 82px }

.bio-text { height: 91px; margin-left: 85px;}

input[type="number"] {border: 2px solid #b1b1b1; padding: .55rem .75rem} 
textarea {border: 2px solid #b1b1b1; padding: .55rem .75rem}

.circle { width: 22px; height: 22px; border-radius: 50%; color: white;
           line-height: 20px; text-align: center; background: rgb(162, 197, 252); }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-container">
<form>
        <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        <label for="inputPhone" >Phone</label>
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
          
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="number" class="form-control " id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          <label >Bio</label>
          
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
          <div class="circle">i</div>
          <label for="inputBio" ></label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
          
            <textarea class="form-control " id="inputBio" rows="3" placeholder="Your Bio"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. There were some changes which I saw in your code and the one with the `<div class="col-sm-1"> <div class="circle">i</div></div>` did the magic and  and <label> is not actually required. **Could you please explain how the circle went new to the bio-text without any margin in css?**

Comment: Its all in the grid layout. As the `col-sm-2`  `col-sm-1` and  `col-sm-9`  fall under the same row, they align horizontal. As these have they width fixed, 
 `col-sm-1`  got pushed near to the bio-text.

Answer (score 1):

Working from your example in fiddle I have managed to line up the form as you specified shown here ... https://jsfiddle.net/x8wmhfL9/4/

Changes I made were as follows:

- To begin with I removed margins that were throwing things of such as
  the box class
- Where ever you used mr-sm- I used col-sm- (I am not sure is mr-sm- is
  a typo or if it is a class I am un aware of, but I do know col-sm-
  should do what you want)
- I used form-group instead of form-inline because I found I could inline your info icon simply by adding  display: inline-block; to the circle class.
- I placed a class around the Bio text and the info icon to help line them up to the phone label width
- I changed col-sm-2 to col-sm-3 and col-sm-10 to col-sm-9, simply because this worked better at the resolutions I was working at, but you may find your original column size work best for you.

I hope this was helpful and that I have explained my changes well enough for you to understand why I made those decisions.

```css
.form-container {
  max-width: 449px
}

.bio-text {
  height: 91px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  border: 2px solid #b1b1b1;
  padding: .55rem .75rem
}

textarea {
  border: 2px solid #b1b1b1;
  padding: .55rem .75rem
}

.circle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(162, 197, 252);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Phone</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone Number">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="">Bio</label>
        <div class="circle">i</div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea class="form-control bio-text" id="inputBio" rows="3" placeholder="Your Bio"></textarea>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But needed the margin for the circle also. Thanks I resolved my issue

Comment: I took out the class for simplicity sake, I should have put it back in once I got it working. Regardless I am glad I could help :D

Comment: Yeah. Thanks again for the kind guidance! Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Just see the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/5cg2u751/).

Adding `col-sm-2` in the label bio will solve the issue. Also remove unnecessary label field like inputBio and class like `mr-sm-2` from the label and textarea.